# unable to load file from url phpoffice/spreadsheet

Tags: phpoffice

Trying to load an .xlsx file from url but it gives error like,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: File 
"http://localhost/test/csvfile/samplesms.xlsx" does not exist. in
D:\wamp\www\test\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File.php on line 137
```

Loading file with below,

```
 $filename = "http://localhost/test/csvfile/samplesms.xlsx";
 $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
 $reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
 $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filename);
```

File is already at given location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

loading from URL is not supported in phpoffice/spreadsheet.

Answer (score 6):

you can load file content using **php_get_content** or **curl** and save it temporary locally then load local version of the file

```
$filename = "http://localhost/test/csvfile/samplesms.xlsx";

$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$inputFileName = 'tempfile.xlsx';
file_put_contents($inputFileName, $file);
/** Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
```